# Spring Integration vs ServiceMix ESB

Tags: spring-integration, esb, apache-servicemix

I am researching for EIP/ESB solution to use in my project.
The first reason is to decouple modules and different sub systems, also refactor some parts to  be easy integrated with 3th party systems. And in future i think that i will need a lot of the EIP like filtering, splitting etc.
I have checked the apache camel + service mix, spring integration. I know about tibco and mule too.
Service mix + camel provide rich stack of components and protocols, but isn't it tied with activeMQ broker. What if i need to use tibco jms implementation if future?
Spring Integration - is it ESB or not? I definitely need some of the pipes(channels) to be in memory for local JVM messaging between some modules, and distributed when messaging is in cluster. Besides that, is SI tied to any jms implementation?

So
Requirements:
-Message routing in local and distributed way
-Easy switching of JMS implementation e.g. now ActiveMQ, after that may be tibco 
-Lightweight 
-Simple
-Full set of standart protocols, components and adaptors - I will not need any thing like twitter, gae and something like that

Also can SI be a distributed ESB like ServiceMix?
I am using spring IoC, Can i use SI with any other ESB like Mule?
Is there any features from using Spring + SI?

Answer (score 1):

Camel is **not** tied to ActiveMQ.

Camel works with any JMS broker, using its camel-jms component.
http://camel.apache.org/jms

Although there is an extended JMS component that has been optimized for ActiveMQ
http://camel.apache.org/activemq

And yes I think Camel + SMX is a powerful combo that supports the needs your write.
It has all the EIPs and Components you need
http://camel.apache.org/eip
http://camel.apache.org/components

Comment: I think SMX is tied to AMQ?
I intend to use SI for now as it is more lightweight and many things come out of the box with spring framework. 
In case i need stand alone ESB i SMX provides integration with SI.

Comment: You can also use just Camel, its an integration framework like SI.